# How can I access a VM console from the command line of another machine

Tags: console, vmware, libvirt, vsphere

I have a VMWare vSphere 5.5 Hypervisor with a RHEL VM running on it.

From my understanding of the documentation at http://libvirt.org/drvesx.html, I believe I should be able to interact fully with the VM using libvirt, via virsh.

However, after connecting to the hypervisor, when I attempt to start a console via:

> virsh -c esx://$USER@$HOST?no_verify=1 console VMNAME

I receive the following:

```
Connected to domain VMNAME
Escape character is ^]
error: this function is not supported by the connection driver: virDomainOpenConsole
```

Am I doing something wrong or does libvirt not allow access to the VM console via an ESX Hypervisor?

Comment: Have you made sure the proper services (Manage -> Security Profile) are running on your ESXi host? ex "ESXi shell". Moreover it is far wiser to use SSH and especially vSphere PowerCLI.

Comment: Stuck in same problem, kindly let me know if you able to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

By the error message, it looks like the ESX driver doesn't allow the user to open a VM console. There's not much to do then...